# C what is happening when printf convers long long to %o (unsigned int)

Tags: c, casting, printf, variadic-functions

I'm trying to replicate printf because I'm not allowed to use the real one in assignments, and I don't understand what is happening when I pass it a value too large:

```
unsigned int n = 4294967286;
printf("%o", n); #=> 37777777766
my_printf("%o", n); #=> 4256507006;
```

I'm getting the value like that:

```
a = (unsigned int)(va_arg(f->l, unsigned int));
```

Then I'm using my `ui_to_s` to get the corresponding string:

```
char *ui_to_s_base(unsigned long long n, int base, const char *base_set)
{
    const char  *defaut_base = "0123456789abcdef";
    char        *res;
    char        *tmp;
    unsigned long long   i;

    tmp = str_new_size(256);
    i = 0;
    tmp[i++] = base_set ? base_set[(n % base)] : defaut_base[(n % base)];
    while ((n /= 10) > 0)
        tmp[i++] = base_set ? base_set[(n % base)] : defaut_base[(n % base)];
    tmp[i] = '\0';
    res = str_reverse(tmp);
    free(tmp);
    return (res);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We need the code for `my_printf`.

Comment: it is way way way too long, I thought I included the relevant parts, how Im getting the value and converting it to a string ?
Edit: please don't just downvote at least leave a comment -.-

Comment: I sincerely doubt that. Besides, you didn't even post the code for `ui_to_s_base` - which to my mind seems highly relevant. Help us out here. ;-)

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post code that isn't working

Comment: I added ui_to_s_base, and printf is about 500 lines I sincerely doubt you wanna read that

Comment: Earlier you showed calling `ui_to_s_base` with  arguments but now you posted that it takes 3 arguments

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `a` is (in a debugger or by printing it with the real `printf` at that point)? Does `ui_to_s_base` work in other contexts? Why `str_new_size` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: Why are you dividing by 10? You should be dividing by `base`.

Comment: The loop `while ((n /= 10) > 0)` is wrong; the divisor should be `base`, not a fixed `10`.  That certainly breaks for octal, base 8.

Comment: @Arkku yes it works in other contexts, and Martin oh god how stupid -.- thanks

Comment: That doesn't explain why `4256507006` was produced instead of `4294967286`

Comment: The 'nonsense' like `tmp[i++] = base_set ? base_set[(n % base)] : defaut_base[(n % base)];` should be neutered by `char *digits = base_set; if (digits == 0) digits = defaut_base;  tmp[i++] = digits[(n % base)];` where the assignment to digits is done once outside the loop.  I'd prefer `default_base` or `default_set` or `default_digits` with the `l` in `default`, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know, but I have to put up with 'nonsense' constraint like 'no more than 20 lines per function, no more than 5 vars, no { at the end of the line, 'for()' is forbidden, etc .. thats why I did this ugly thing that is write-only code.

Comment: Ah, a coding standard that actively discourages good code. Let me guess: homework assignment?

Comment: @MartinTörnwall Sadly yes

Comment: Since there are only 4 variables in the function, you could add a fifth as I suggested.  You could also use `static const char default_digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";` as a file-scope constant (or function-scope constant — it isn't a variable), or simply use `const char *digits = base_set; if (digits == 0) digits = "0123456789abcdef";` which avoids the extra variable (and is const-correct, to boot).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not allowed to define and initialize on the same line (except for const and static) it would make me go over the 20 lines, also I can't go over 80 columns. There is so much I would do differently without those shackles :/
static const char might work, all on one line, I'm gonna try it! thanks (btw not allowed to use if without {} and not allowed to have everything on the same line for the if.. see the nonsense ?)

Comment: You're being taught garbage.  200 lines; yes — I can sympathize.  50 lines; maybe, though there are places when more are appropriate.  If you use a `do { ... } while ((n /= base) > 0);` loop, you don't need to repeat that monstrosity of an assignment expression.  If you don't allow a null set of digits (so `base_set` must be supplied by the caller), you don't need the monstrosity.  You can use `char tmp[256];` to avoid the need to free (or `char tmp[24];` which is long enough for 64-bit `unsigned long long`).  Etc.  You aren't out of options yet!

Comment: do while is also forbidden hahaha, only while, but those suggestions are really awesone thank you so much I'm gonna try em!

Comment: so much down votes I really don't get it :/ sure the mistake was silly but the question was not so bad, was it ?

Comment: What language are you being taught? It isn't C, at any rate. Or, rather, you will have to remember later that the rules imposed on you are not rules imposed by C but rules imposed by an…well, it's tempting to say 'imbecile', but perhaps that's too harsh…'misguided teacher'. Also, when you do face such constraints, it is crucial that you explain them — or give a URL pointer to the rules — so that people can actually help you. Eliciting the rules bit-by-bit like this is excruciating. You're unlikely to ever encounter anything so draconian in industry — or, if you do, you can look elsewhere.

Comment: Haha yes it's C, I can't really say publicly what school it is, as it is entirely funded by ********(had to delete it can't leave it public) also not allowed to post the 'guidelines' which arent guidelines because you get a 0 (or F in the US system) for any project that has at least 1 mistake like one more line or one more column or a code badly indented on one line, the first mistake is fatal :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72184/discussion-between-itsasecret-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ((n /= 10) > 0)
```

You should be dividing by `base`. 10 will work like a charm just as long as you ask it to print in decimal.

I guess the moral of the story here is that if you have a bug in some code that contains a nontrivial constant, that is probably a good place to start investigating.

Comment: Still I don't think I deserved those agressive downvotes, but thank you very much.

Comment: I had no part in the downvoting.